# How to fix corupted icons on home screen?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, home-screen-shortcuts

ALL of the shortcuts for the apps that I installed (not preinstalled ones on a ROM), all of them sudden got corrupt. They all show upd now with "Android Logo" icon and not the icon of the program. T-Mobile TV is installed on a ROM, so the icon for that is fine, but take an app "Movies", the icon for that is corrupt and instead of icon of this program, I have a little "android logo" icon. How do I restore all of messed up icons?

Reboot does not help. I tried SD card mount/unmount with no luck

Comment: Are these apps that you've moved to the SD card?

Comment: yes. They are..

Comment: If you remove one of the apps from the home screen and then add it back manually, does the correct icon show up?

Answer (score 1):

If you move an app to/from the sdcard, and you have icons on the home screen, you need to remove and re-add the icon to the home screen. when I have done this, I thought the icons removed themselves from the home screen automatically.

When you move it to/from the sdcard, it is a lot like uninstalling the application (without removing the user data) and re-installing it again in the new location.

Comment: I can not re-drag it on home screen. All of them (about 15) also disappeared from all-apps-overview

Comment: I was hoping for a refresh-all-icons.exe solution

Comment: if you can't even re-add them, then there is another issue. They are not installed correctly once they were moved to the sdcard. maybe they don't support running from the sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

i have seen this one worked! you have to restart the launcher of the android.

> I had this problem where all my apps stored on my SD card that had
>   shortcuts stored within folders had the generic Android logo. This
>   happened everytime I restarted my phone or unmounted then mounted my
>   SD card. Right the fix......... go into settings/applications/manage
>   applications/all and navigate to your launcher. I'm using a HTC desire
>   hd so.my launcher is HTC sense. Some peeps may have installed a third
>   party launcher. Anyways click force stop. Then press the home button.
>   Your launcher should now restart. Your icon logos should now be back
>   to normal and will be normal everytime you restart your phone.

http://www.droidforums.net/forum/thunderbolt-tech-support/147067-icons-pics-won-t-appear-after-restart.html

Answer (score 0):

the problem is sometimes fixed when I insert sim card. normaly I do not have sim card in my phone and then it goes back to corrupted when I remove it.